# Bluegiga Bluetooth LED USB dongle firmware update tool not working correctly

Tags: windows, bluetooth, usb, libusb, firmware

So I was following step by step BlueGiga's BGDemo application note but ran into a problem when using the dfutool.exe to update my USB dongle's firmware.  The steps I took are as follow:

1. Open BLEGUI and connect to my USB dongle.
2. Press DFU to restart the USB device in DFU mode.
3. Windows says driver not found so I point the driver installer to the windrv folder and it successfully installs.
4. Under device manager's libusb devices tab, the device shows up in DFU mode.
5. If I look in properties and look at the Hardware IDs of the dongle, it says VID:2458 and PID:FFFE (which is EXACTLY what the documentation says)
6. I go to command prompt and run the command "....\bin\dfutool.exe 2458:FFFE out.hex" which is EXACTLY what they say

BUT the command prompt gives me an error "device:2458:fffe not found" which is REALLY boggling my mind since it shows up in device manager as a libusb device with the exact same hardware IDs.  Does anyone have ANY clue what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't ask the manufacturer of the dongle? They should offer technical support for such cases.

Comment: I just followed those instructions myself and it worked for me. Wish I could help

Comment: I know the thread's closed and it's over a year later, but in case anyone runs into similar issues in the future--as I did this morning--you can't reboot the device into DFU mode until you've Attached to it in BLE GUI, and until you've done so trying to flash the firmware will result in the same error message, "device:2458:fffe not found". (I don't think this was exactly the OP's issue, but thought it worth a mention since this step wasn't called out explicitly.)

Comment: To add to user1454265 comment. The dongle MUST be in DFU mode. If it's an unflashed BLED112 dongle (factory settings), then it should work with the instructions given. If it has been reflashed with other firmware then things get more dicey. If the firmware has a DFU entry point, i.e., it calls system_reset, then you have to use that to get the dongle into DFU mode. If you do not have a DFU entry point, then the dongle is stuck with that firmware. There is a way to get it unstuck, but really, you're better off buying a new dongle at that point.